# Why does IntelliJ not see javaFx?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

Why does IntelliJ not see javafx? I thought that it comes with the java JDK.
[image]

Comment: JavaFX used to be included with **Oracle's** distribution of the JDK. It was never part of all OpenJDK distributions (e.g., on Linux). But Oracle has not included JavaFX in the JDK as of Java/JavaFX version 11. Some vendors, however, still provide JDK/JRE distributions that include JavaFX (see [jewelsea's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72904732/6395627)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaFX only comes with some JDK distributions (e.g. Azul Zulu JDK FX or BellSoft Liberica Full JDK), see the:

- [Installation section of the JavaFX tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info).

Official documentation is at:

- [Getting started with JavaFX on openjfx.io](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/).

Quick start with Idea is the:

- [Create new JavaFX project wizard](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html).